# What's the purpose of min_retries for RetryParams?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

In the RetryParams documentation, there are min_retries and max_retries params. I can understand having a max_retries param, but not sure what the point of having min_retries. The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class) shows the following:

```
min_retries
The minimum number of times to retry.
max_retries
The maximum number of times to retry. Set this value to 0 if you don't want any retries.
```

If I set max_retries to 10, I would hope that if a connection repeatedly failed, it would try up to 10 times. Why would a min_retries param be necessary? When would that come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that documentation page:

```
max_retry_period
The maximum number of seconds that can be spent on all retries of a given request. Retry stops when this period passed AND min_retries has been attempted.
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

From [appengine-docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/RetryParams):

"[..] This proceeds until either the request is successful, retryMaxAttempts are made, **or both** retryMinAttempts are made **and** totalRetryPeriodMillis have elapsed.[..]"

In my own words: your request takes an unknown amount of time until it fails, there are two parameters you can use to limit the total time for and/or the number of repeated requests, whatever is reached the first.
Lets say you wanna ensure that (repeated) requests wont take longer than 10 seconds, but you want to have a minimum of 2 repeated requests at any case, even if it would need more than 10 secs in that case.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the answer.